# rails 3 ruby 1.8.7 app slow startup on the web

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, startup, ruby-1.8.7

ive been working with rails 3 and ruby 1.8.7 and ALWAYS (in all my apps), 
i have problems with the STARTUP time delay.

it sometimes loads ok, and sometimes takes more than 12 seconds (or more) just to start loading the site.

one of my sites

http://www.tuwebenlaweb2.com.ar/
or
http://www.tuwebenlaweb3.com.ar/

is there something i could do to test my apps or change some configs to make STARTUP faster??

thanks

joaquin

Comment: How are you hosting your apps?  VPS company, stack you are using is good info.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not an answer, but when I ping your site, I'm getting dropped packets. So there seems to be a network disruption somewhere on your server or datacenter.

```
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=165.655 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=432.985 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=426.050 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=399.613 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=434.376 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=6 ttl=45 time=434.430 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=7 ttl=45 time=434.368 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=8 ttl=45 time=434.478 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=9 ttl=45 time=434.232 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=10 ttl=45 time=434.676 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=11 ttl=45 time=272.736 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=13 ttl=45 time=434.228 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=14 ttl=45 time=433.443 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=15 ttl=45 time=434.299 ms
64 bytes from 208.113.217.188: icmp_seq=16 ttl=45 time=434.369 ms
```

This might be a better question for server fault.com

Comment: in your console type "ping tuwebenlaweb2.com.ar".  If packets are dropping then it takes longer to fulfill requests.